# Dementia Nursing Home Fines?

Tags: dementia, medical-billing

I'm looking for a nursing home for my grandmother with dementia.  I found a nice review site and I noticed that many of the nursing homes received fines from Medicare.  Why is this?

http://review.care

http://review.care/nursinghome/id/13259/retirement-and-nursing-center-austin-austin-tx